# Relation of change of basis matrix from basis $A$ to basis $B$ and from $B$ to $A$

Tags: matrices

Given the basis $A$ and $B$, and given $M_1$ a change of basis matrix from $A$ to $B$, and $M_2$ from $B$ to $A$.

How do I find the relation between $M_1$ and $M_2$?

I know that $M_2 = M_1^{-1}$ but I dont know how to get to this relation, given that the only information I know is $M_1 = B^{-1} * A$ and $M_2 = A^{-1} * B$

How do I prove that $B^{-1} * A$ is the inverse of $A^{-1} * B$ ?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I prove that $B^{-1}A$ is the inverse of $A^{-1} B$

Recall the definition of inverse:

> A square matrix $A$ is said to be invertible if there exists a $B$ such that 
>   $$AB = BA = I$$

Thus, we just need to verify that

$$(B^{-1} A)(A^{-1} B) = I$$
and
$$(A^{-1} B)(B^{-1} A) = I$$

which shows that it satisfies the definition of inverse.

Comment: good! but supposing I dont know that M1 is the inverse of M2, how can I discover that ?

Comment: I did not assume that $M_1$ is inverse to $M_2$, but rather I showed it. Do you mean if we don't know that $M_1 = B^{-1} A$ and $M_2 = A^{-1} B$?

Comment: yes, i meant that also

Comment: Rigorously proving it would depend on your definition of change of basis matrix. You should be able to intuitively see it by changing basis from A to B to A is the same and similarly B to A to B.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Given basis $A$ and $B$, consider the change of basis matrix $M_{1}$ from $A$ to $B$ and the change of basis matrix $M_{2}$ from $B$ to $A$.

For all $v\in V$ (it is written in the canonical basis), $v_{A}$ is the vector $v$ in the basis $A$ and $v_{B}$ is the vector $v$ in the basis $B$. Then $$(M_{2}M_{1})v_{A}=M_{2}(M_{1}v_{A})=M_{2}v_{B}=v_{A}$$ and $$(M_{1}M_{2})v_{B}=M_{1}(M_{2}v_{B})=M_{1}v_{A}=v_{B}.$$
Therefore, for uniqueness, $M_{1}M_{2}=I$.